# Pythonic way of parsing this string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm parsing this `line`-

```
0386          ; Greek # L&       GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS
```

Basically, I need -

```
point = 0386
script = Greek
```

And I'm doing it like this,

```
point = line.split(";")[0].replace(" ","")
script = line.split("#")[0].split(";")[1].replace(" ","")
```

I'm not convinced that what I'm doing is the most pythonic way of doing it, is there a more elegant way of doing this? Maybe a regex one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with unbound method [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> line = '0386      ; Greek # L&   GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS'
>>> point, script = map(str.strip, line.split('#')[0].split(';'))
>>> point
'0386'
>>> script
'Greek'
```

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> point, script = [word.strip() for word in line.split('#')[0].split(';')]
>>> point
'0386'
>>> script
'Greek'
```

Comment: This looks very concise, although I prefer not using `map`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, I added list comprehension version.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Why not a `map`? How would it affect the performance?

Comment: @ComputerFellow LCs are generally faster than `map`s.

Comment: This kind of speed difference should never matter. list comprehensions are usually preferred to `map` because they are easier to read.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Thank you! Will keep them in my mind, I'll profile them sometime :)

Comment: +1 this answer cannot get any better BTW @GamesBrainiac LC's are faster than `map`'s ????

Comment: @KDawG Yes. Always use LCs when you're able to.

Comment: @KDawG Take a look at Burhan's answer. Its beautiful and concise.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a regex one liner:

```
point, script = re.search("^(\d+)\s*;\s*(\S+)\s*.*$",s).groups()
```

where `s` is your string, and of course you need to `import re`

Comment: `("^(.*)\s+;\s+(.*)\s+#.*$", s).groups()` worked for me. The above didn't.

Comment: @ComputerFellow, Your regex matches the number with the white space after it. But if it works for you I'm glad! Anyway, the point here is to show how you do it with a regex in one line.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> code, desc = line[:line.rfind('#')].split(';')
>>> code.strip()
'0386'
>>> desc.strip()
'Greek'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would've done it:

```
>>> s = "0386          ; Greek # L&       GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS"
>>> point = s.split(';')[0].strip()
>>> point
'0386'
>>> script = s.split(';')[1].split('#')[0].strip()
>>> script
'Greek'
```

Note that you can re-use `s.split(';')`. So perhaps saving it to a `var` would be a good idea:

```
>>> var = s.split(';')
>>> point = var[0].strip()  # Strip gets rid of all the whitespace
>>> point
'0386'
>>> script = var[1].split('#')[0].strip()
>>> script
'Greek'
```